# Checking linear independence efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a 3×3 matrix A whose columns represent vectors v1,v2,v3 in R$^3$. All the vectors are linearly independent. Now, given a vector v4 I want to replace one of the vectors leaving the new matrix independent. I want to replace the earliest vector: if v4, v2, v3 is independent then replace v1, else if v1, v4, v3 is independent – replace v2, else – replace v3. What is the most efficient way of doing this? I can only think of checking linear independence of the both options.

**Edit:**

*The problem description:*

I want to build a sort of linear regression model with six independent variables (I used three variables in the question for simplicity). All the data come from sensors which are updated regularly. I would like to base the prediction on the latest data. So I decided to put the last three independent variables to matrix and just solve the resulted linear system to find the parameter vector. I think such model should work for a short period of time. The problem is that often the matrix is singular, so I need to find a way to use the latest three vectors of variables which are linear independent.

Comment: It should be quite efficient to calculate the determinant of every matrix in question.

Comment: That depends on how you define efficiency, but my first instinct would be to construct a $3\times 4$ matrix with columns $v_4,v_3,v_2,v_1$ in that order, and then row reduce.  The positions of the $1$'s correspond to the columns to keep in your desired final output.

Comment: @KurtG., Thanks, but I have a bigger matrix actually and I would like to find the more efficient way

Comment: See ? How big ?

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, I will check your approach

Comment: @KurtG. 6x6, and I should calculate on embedding device so performance is important

Comment: Python (even though it uses an interpreter rather than a compiler) is very fast at calculating the determinants of even larger matrices. $6\times 6$ is nothing. What is an embedding device exactly ? I get the feeling we are about to leave he realm of mathematics.

Comment: @KurtG. the device is Aduino Leonardo. I am requesting a sensor at 100 Hz and now I see that there is no much time left

Comment: It is clear that MSE isn't programming site. I see three options: 1. try determinants, 2. try row reduce (JMorawitz) 3. take one step back and give some background *why* you want to do this. We need a mathematical problem. Perhaps there is a fast way to do it differently when we know what exactly the wider tasks are. Presumably a geometric problem.

Comment: @KurtG. please see my edits